# H.264 hardware encoding for live video stream from Google Glass

Tags: android, video, google-glass

I am trying to make a video stream from Google Glass to a local server.
For start, as a test, I've tried the SpyDroid v9.1.
The streaming using H.263 encoding works perfectly, but the quality is not quite good.
    When trying to live stream with an H.264 hardware encoding, the connection fails.
The received error is: "Error: stsd box could not be found", thrown from here:

```
public StsdBox getStsdBox() throws IOException {
                try {
                        return new StsdBox(fis,getBoxPos("/moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stsd"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new IOException("Error: stsd box could not be found");
                }
        }
```

Also, since for now Glass has Android 15, the MediaCodec class (android.media.MediaCodec) is not available(Media API was added in Android 16).

A similar issue was raised to Google, but no real working solution:
a. https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=207.
b. https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/issues/detail?id=129

Does anyone know how can a H.264 hardware encoding live video stream can be sent from Google Glass?

Any help/guide on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to wait for XE14 (moving to KitKat compatibility) ... no formal date but end of February was originally targeted.  I don't know whether the "wearables" SDK targeted for about 2 weeks from now bears any relationship with XE14.

Answer (score 2):

The SoC in glass does not support VP8, only h263/h264 and since google is pushing for VP8 on all its products there will be no hw acceleration provided by google on the glass. Source: last IO's talk on glass software development.

A possible solution is porting the [gstreamer-ducati](https://github.com/robclark/gst-ducati) libraries to glass and using them to directly talk to the video acceleration hardware on the omap4 SoC (IVA-HD).